# slow to orderby desc on left join

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I need a little help.

i wrote the below left join query and it works well without ORDER BY

```
select members.membership_no,members.first_name,members.last_name,employment.position,members.start_date 
from members 
LEFT JOIN employment ON employment.membership_no=members.membership_no limit 10
```

But as soon as I add ORDER BY DESC to it,it becomes really slow .

```
select members.membership_no,members.first_name,members.last_name,employment.position,members.start_date 
from members 
LEFT JOIN employment ON employment.membership_no=members.membership_no  
ORDER BY members.membership_no DESC  limit 10
```

Am i doing something wrong ?,How can i do this left join and get results in descending order but limited to 10 results , is there any other way ?

Comment: Do you have an index for members.membership_no (or is it a primary key)?

Comment: Thanks I got it now , seems membership_no  was not primary key but auto increment id column was , so I just set  membership_no  as index and now it works ... thanks .

Comment: Feel free to submit (and accept) this as an answer/delete the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important note for doing ORDER BY  DESC  using left joins.

Both tables a and b must have indexes  and incase if you happen to do a join on a column that does not have an Index or is not a primary key , Than you must set a index on that column .

So in the above query membership_no was not primary key but auto increment id column was , so I just set membership_no as index  it worked

Comment: Please post your A) current query and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE employment; C) SHOW CREATE members; so we can see your ending query and table definitions.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue in the instance of this query, was that by using ORDER BY in a query, MySQL is unable to use the index if the ORDER BY expressions are different.

**Related links:**

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html
- http://mysqldba.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/how-to-pick-indexes-for-order-by-and.html

Comment: “ if the ORDER BY expressions are different.” You might want to rephrase that.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing apples and oranges.  The `order by` clause is a big difference in the queries.

Without the `order by`, MySQL can just run the results and return rows as they are found.  It will quickly find 10 and stop.

With the `order by`, MySQL needs to generate the entire result set and then order it.  Only after the ordering can it fetch the first 10 rows.  This is a much longer process.

You are using a `LEFT JOIN`, so all rows in the first table are being kept in the result set.  You can optimize this particular query by filtering down to 10 members first, running the query, and filtering again:

```
select m.membership_no, m.first_name, m.last_name, e.position, m.start_date 
from (select m.*
      from members m
      order by m.membership_no desc
      limit 10
     ) m left join
     employment e 
     on e.membership_no = m.membership_no  
order by m.membership_no desc
limit 10;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help really helpful but  I solved it for my case the slowness was indeed the index and also i made a silly mistake  of my membership_no  being of 2 different data types, in one table decimal and in another varchar .

so i converted both to decimal and boom from 3 to 4 seconds the queries went to 0.032 seconds.

 just for comparison i did a test with 10k records using sub select you provided  and its  time was  0.063 seconds   and than i did it using my left join 10k records  time was  0.032..